# Windows 10 account disappear

Tags: windows, windows-10, user

When I install Windows 10 on my computer, I choose to erase all data from disk an create a fresh installation. I create a new local user (not a Microsoft account) and name it Jorane.

I use it without any problems for 3 days but today, I "lost" administrator rights for my account : when an app needed elevation the "Yes" button where not present and I could only say "No".

I boot in Safe-Mode to change my account type. I go in `Control Panel/User Accounts/User Accounts/Manage Accounts` and see something strange : my account had disappear. The only account was "Administrator". So I reboot in normal mode to find a solution on internet. But once again, only the administrator account is available to log in.

I had never created any administrator account in Windows 10 an had to boot again in Safe-Mode in order to change Administrator password, wich I never set. I created another account (Fuhonjud) in order to go in the internet, the Administrator built-in can't open edge.

I though that my account was perhaps deleted, but it's not : if I open an administrator CMD and list users:

```
C:\Windows\system32>net users:
User accounts for \\ORIONDE

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator            DefaultAccount           defaultuser0
Fuhonjud                 Guest                    Jorane
The command completed successfully.
```

Account "Jorane" is here

If I activate my account :

`C:\Windows\system32>net user Jorane \activated:yes
The command completed successfully`

But the account doesn't appears in Control Panel:

[image: Control Panel]

If I open lusrmgr.msc I could also see my account Jorane and my other account Fuhonjud. If I tried to create a new account named "Jorane", Windows refused because it already exists. The folder `C:\Users\Jorane` exists. I search a lot about this on the internet but can't find any solution for this.

I only have few applications on my account Jorane and can use the new account instead. I need your help in order to understand what append to Windows, if you already seen this and if anybody know how to fix it.

Comment: this either could be a complex or easy solution. Can you create a new user with another name?

Comment: can you go into system properties, environment variables, and take a screen-shot and upload it to your question? Label like so "additional detail for the nerds" like this: https://i.gyazo.com/5cc51ef6bb4117eab6df79e3330883d4.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely problem is that the account is disabled. This command didn't do what you expected:

```
net user Jorane \activated:yes
```

`\activated` is not a switch. Rather, that command reset the password on the `Jorane` account to `\activated:yes`. You want to run this command:

```
net user Jorane /active:yes
```

Note the forward slash and the spelling of `active`.

Also, a user won't show up unless it's a member of Users or Administrators. You can use the `net localgroup` command to list the members of a group. For instance, this lists the members of Administrators:

```
net localgroup Administrators
```

If `Jorane` isn't a member of either Administrators or Users, you'll need to add it to one of those. This adds it to Administrators:

```
net localgroup Administrators Jorane /add
```

Comment: I forgot to say that : in graphical mode, I could saw that the option "Account is disable" was not ticked, so I think the problem was my account weren't in any groups.Adding the account in Administrators group solved the problem, thanks you very much !

Comment: What can I say... you saved me